# Android: res/strings.xml, include another strings file from another folder

Tags: android, xml, string, include, adt

How can include other strings from another xml on another location in the file system?

For example:

```
<xi:include href="assets/app.xml" parse="xml" />
```

But example above doesn't work, what is the right syntax? Cannot find anything by google on it.

Maybe you want to know why? Well, long story but want to automate some projects and generate content in the assets folder (and reuse). This is the reason it is on another location. The only thing I have to is press run in ADT.

Is it possible to include some other strings from another location?

content of app.xml in the assets folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Example application</string>
    <string name="app_author">Erwin</string>
    <string name="app_copyright">illumation (c) 2014</string>
    <string name="app_favicon">assets/appicon.ico</string>
    <string name="app_icon">assets/appicon.png</string>
    <string name="app_icon_large">assets/appicon-large.png</string>
    <string name="app_launch_image">assets/applaunch.png</string>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, all String Resources that you wish to access with `R.string.string_name` (in Java) or `@string/string_name` (in XML) identifiers must be in `.xml` files located directly in the `/res/values` directory of your project (i.e., no subdirectories either).

However, the filenames are arbitrary and you may essentially have as many files as you like. The main requirement is that all String Resources be located within a `<resources>` tag. As long as each Resource is inside that tag, and each file is in the above-mentioned directory, then it will be compiled into your `R.java`.

Of course, this doesn't help in your situation.

I should also point out that you cannot modify your Assets programmatically. If your goal by doing this is to keep the data private to your app, then you probably want to use the `openFileOuput()`, `openFileInput()`, and `getFilesDir()` methods with standard `File` and `Stream` objects. These are covered [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal).

If it is necessary that you use the XML format, then you've a few different options for parsing XML, some of which are detailed [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html). I've used the `XmlPullParser`, and it is quite easy to implement.

Comment: This doesn't help my situation ;-) But hey, thanks for the clear explanation.

Comment: I added a couple of links that might help you develop a work-around for your issue. I'm not sure if your eventual solution absolutely must use Assets, but I would think that standard File access is a viable option.

Comment: Thanks for the extra comments. Well, I create some webapps that uses mostly the same project structure. The webapps will be created with use of the browser and after completion it will be 'compiled' into the assets directory as compact as is possible. It would be nice that without any project customization, I can press the compile button and et viola, a new app is born.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure if I fully grasp your aim, but would it be possible to create your base app, then just copy/replace the necessary xml file to the assets folder, and compile? Or maybe you want to automate this process?

Comment: If it possible without moving things around, it would be nice ;-)

Comment: I guess I don't understand the purpose/intention. Sorry I couldn't help. But the short answer to "How can include other strings from another xml on another location in the file system?" is "You can't."

Comment: Maybe if you rephrase your question, make your end-goal more explicit, somebody else can give you some ideas.